# Carousel effect using android-supportv4.viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, carousel

I need an example of view pager with carousel effect.I've searched through internet but I couldn't find any example.So , have you done anything like this before ? Do you have any examples that I can examine.[image]

Comment: You can use GalleryCoverFlow.

Answer (score 4):

You need:

- activity_main
- item
- Custom Fragment
- Custom LinearLayout
- CustomPagerAdapter
- Activity

I use this code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.thedeveloperworldisyours.carouselviewpager.MainActivity">


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.thedeveloperworldisyours.carouselviewpager.CustomLinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/item_size_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/item_content"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
    </com.thedeveloperworldisyours.carouselviewpager.CustomLinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Custom Fragment

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance(Activity context, int position, float scale) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", position);
        bundle.putFloat("scale", scale);
        return Fragment.instantiate(context, CustomFragment.class.getName(), bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);

        int position = this.getArguments().getInt("position");
        TextView textView = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(position));

        CustomLinearLayout root = (CustomLinearLayout) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_root);
        float scale = this.getArguments().getFloat("scale");
        root.setScaleBoth(scale);

        return linearLayout;
    }
}
```

Custom LinearLayout

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private float mScale = BIG_SCALE;

    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setScaleBoth(float scale) {
        this.mScale = scale;
        this.invalidate();    // If you want to see the mScale every time you set
        // mScale you need to have this line here,
        // invalidate() function will call onDraw(Canvas)
        // to redraw the view for you
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // The main mechanism to display mScale animation, you can customize it
        // as your needs
        int w = this.getWidth();
        int h = this.getHeight();
        canvas.scale(mScale, mScale, w / 2, h / 2);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

The most import thing is the adapter

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    public final static float BIG_SCALE = 1.0f;
    public final static float SMALL_SCALE = 0.7f;
    public final static float DIFF_SCALE = BIG_SCALE - SMALL_SCALE;

    private Activity mContext;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private float mScale;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Activity context, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // make the first mViewPager bigger than others
        if (position == FIRST_PAGE)
            mScale = BIG_SCALE;
        else
            mScale = SMALL_SCALE;

        return CustomFragment.newInstance(mContext, position, mScale);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
        CustomLinearLayout myLinearLayout = (CustomLinearLayout) page.findViewById(R.id.item_root);
        float scale = BIG_SCALE;
        if (position > 0) {
            scale = scale - position * DIFF_SCALE;
        } else {
            scale = scale + position * DIFF_SCALE;
        }
        if (scale < 0) scale = 0;
        myLinearLayout.setScaleBoth(scale);
    }
}
```

and now the Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static int PAGES = 5;
    public final static int FIRST_PAGE = 0  ;

    public CustomPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    public ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_view_pager);

        mAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this, this.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, mAdapter);

        // Set current item to the middle page so we can fling to both
        // directions left and right
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(FIRST_PAGE);

        // Necessary or the mViewPager will only have one extra page to show
        // make this at least however many pages you can see
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        // Set margin for pages as a negative number, so a part of next and
        // previous pages will be showed
        mViewPager.setPageMargin(-400);
    }
}
```

Also you check [this Tutorial](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/carousel-viewpager/#sthash.rtkOS5m2.dpbs) and this exmple in [GitHub.](https://github.com/thedeveloperworldisyours/CarouselViewPager)

Comment: Negative margins should not be used. As stated by Google UI engineers: ``...never supported and not going to in future``.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the link below as solution to implement Carousel in android using View Pager:

https://github.com/haerulmuttaqin/SwipeViewPager

[image: Swipe View Pager is a good representation of Carousel in Android]

Hope it helps anyone looking for answers.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at [CarouselView](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview). 
Might help you if you need a simple carouselview.

Add view in your layout:

```
<com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
    android:id="@+id/carouselView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    app:pageColor="#00000000"
    app:radius="6dp"
    app:slideInterval="3000"
    app:strokeColor="#FF777777"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"/>
```

Add images by implementing callback:

```
    public class SampleCarouselViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CarouselView carouselView;

    int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.image_1, R.drawable.image_2, R.drawable.image_3, R.drawable.image_4, R.drawable.image_5};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_carousel_view);

        carouselView = (CarouselView) findViewById(R.id.carouselView);
        carouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);

        carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);
    }

    ImageListener imageListener = new ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {
            imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position]);
        }
    };
}
```